# Pyinstaller error- requires at least one scriptname file

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

after trying to build a standalone by entering

> python pyinstaller.py -F myscript.py

in the pyinstaller directory i get an error:

> error: Requires at least one scriptname file or exactly one .specfile

I have the script in the same directory as the pyinstaller. What might be causing the error?

EDIT: To answer the comments: I run the command from the same directory as pyinstaller. I can access both files.

Comment: from which directory are you running this command. Is it the same directory that has `myscript.py`. if you type `dir` in the cmd is your script listed. even if pyinstaller might be in the `PATH`, the script given to it as an argument has to be in form of a full/absolute path or it has to exist in the current directory

Comment: both pyinstaller and myscript are in the same folder.

Comment: are you running the command from within that folder?

Comment: yes, i have changed the working dir to the current folder

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-m` after python.
Also, from what I have seen, and tried, "pyinstaller.py" doesn't work, but after removing the ".py" it works

So, perhaps you can try the following:

`python -m PyInstaller -F myscript.py`

Note: 'PyInstaller' in this case is case sensitive, it doesn't work if you just use 'pyinstaller'

'pyinstaller' does work however in the following case: `pyinstaller -F myscript.py`